# Мы вроде не в Америке живём(,) или я не прав?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, или

Можете сказать, нужна ли эта запятая? Я думаю, что да, так как первая часть — это не вопрос, а вторая часть — вопрос таки.

1. Мы вроде не в Америке живём, или я не прав?
2. Мы вроде не в Америке живём или я не прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Мы вроде не в Америке живём, или я не прав?***

Я бы поставила запятую, так как первое предложение в этом ССП является повествовательным (утвердительным), а второе — вопросительным.

> В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами *и, да* (в значении «и»), *или, либо* **запятая не ставится** в следующих случаях: <...>
> **5)** если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы...

Вот похожее предложение:
*Мы же не в XIX веке живём, или я не прав?* (И. Атаманенко. Лицензия на вербовку).

Очень часто предложения такого типа разбиваются на два:
*У них все и всегда делается ради денег. Или я не прав?* (А. Белозеров);
*Но сомневаюсь, что там наилучшим образом налажено медобслуживание. Или я не права?* (Д. Донцова).

[Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) (ПАС под ред. Лопатина)